# ptr_map inserting

Tags: c++, boost, types, insert, boost-ptr-container

I have some predefined type which inherits boost::noncopyable (so I have to store the pointer at these objects). I use a **boost::ptr_map**. As I know, the second argument in it is already a pointer. So, the code:

```
ptr_map<string, boost::any> SomeMap;
typedef %Some noncopyable class/signature% NewType;

// Inserting now
boost::any *temp = new boost::any(new KeyEvent());
SomeMap.insert("SomeKey", temp);
```

The error is:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::ptr_map<std::basic_string<char>, boost::any>::insert(const char [11], boost::any*&)’`

---

**UPD**: When I don't pass the pointer to the any `any temp = any(new KeyEvent());`

I get:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::ptr_map<std::basic_string<char>, boost::any>::insert(const char [11], boost::any&)’`

Comment: Why not `SomeMap["SomeKey"] = temp;`?

Comment: @Cubbi: that will compile, but it won't be exception safe. `temp` will leak if either the string constructor or the empty element insertion throws.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: You're right. That's what I get for using only smart pointers for several years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This version of `insert` takes the key by non-const reference, which means you can't use a temporary as the first value. This is to prevent memory leaks; in your code, `temp` would leak if the string constructor were to throw.

You must either create the key object before creating the raw pointer:

```
string key("SomeKey");
any* temp = new whatever;
SomeMap.insert(key, temp);
```

or use an `auto_ptr` to ensure that the object is deleted whatever happens:

```
auto_ptr<any> temp(new whatever);
SomeMap.insert("SomeKey", temp);
```

Comment: I like second way but it throws the error: `no matching function for call to ‘std::auto_ptr<boost::any>::auto_ptr(NewType*)’`

Comment: auto_ptr is deprecated, I know it's to be avoided in STL containers, not sure about this boost map. I thought the intention for ptr_map was to pass the value as a pointer